# Sending BitCoins using Electrum JSON-RPC

Tags: php, bitcoin, json-rpc

I am trying to send bitcoins using electrum jsonrpc, but it keeps showing "invalid parameters" error.

That is how I call payto method.

```
public function payTo($dest, $amount, $source, $fee)
 {
      return $this->sendRequest('payto', ['destination' => $dest, 'amount' => $amount, 'fee' => $fee, 'from_addr' => $source]);
 }
public function sendRequest($method, $params = [])
 {
      $request = $this->client->request('POST', '/', [
           'json' => [
                'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
                'method' => $method,
                'params' => $params,
                'id' => 'curltext'
           ],
           'auth' => ['user', ''],
      ]);

      $response = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents());
      if (isset($response->error)) {
         throw new Exception($response->error->message);
     } else {
         return $response->result;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonrpc requires the `id` to be an incrementing number, not `curltext`

Comment: Changed to `time()` but it's still not working. Argument that is causing error is "from_addr".